# Trying to add linebreaks to every found pattern in string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a long string of email addresses, and I need to add a line break to the end of every ".edu" in javascript and write it to the innerHTML of a  I'm not very sure how to do this though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please share your attempts

Comment: is there any seperator between the addresses? like comma or something like that?

Comment: No separators in the string unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have any separator you can use the '.edu' as a separator because you know that It will be founded in any email you have, so you can try something like this:

**JS**

```
var str = 'mail1@mail1.edumail2@mail2.edumail3@mail.edumail4@mail4.edumail5@mail5.edu';

var emails = str.split('.edu');

var result = document.getElementById('result');
for(var i = 0, len = emails.length; i < len; i++){
 if(emails[i]){ 
   result.innerHTML += '<p>'+ emails[i] +'.edu</p>';
 }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="result">

</div>
```

*I don't know exactly what you mean about a 'line break' but this solution fits for what you need, you just need to replace the string that is placed in the result div for the whatever you want show.*

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/QwwzPE).